# Leaflet in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Data frame is a

Sample Data is as follows

```
ID    Lat        Long   Address  
1   12.904249 77.70253    1/2 CA    
2   21.221475 72.81281    2/3 DC  
3   23.039251 72.58388    3/5 HJ  

library (leaflet)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Lat Long Address Mapping in R"),
    fluidRow(
      mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                    tabPanel("Map", 
                             bootstrapPage(
                               tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
                               leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "100%"),
                               absolutePanel(
                                 top = 80,
                                 left = 30,

                               )
                             )
                    )
  ,
  server = function(input, output,session) {
    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
        leaflet(a) %>%
          addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
          addMarkers(lng = ~Long, lat = ~Lat,
                     popup = ~address)})
```

The output shows blank screen in shiny

However when I run this code standalone it works and plots the map

```
leaflet(a) %>%
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
  addMarkers(lng = ~Long, lat = ~Lat,
             popup = ~Address)
```

Some issue with shiny code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be from having `height = "100%"` in `leafletOutput` within your `tabPanel`. I did find a relevant solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31278938/how-can-i-make-my-shiny-leafletoutput-have-height-100-while-inside-a-navbarpa). This is based on [SuperZip](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/blob/master/063-superzip-example/ui.R) ui.

```
ui = fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Lat Long Address Mapping in R"),
    fluidRow(
      mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                    tabPanel("Map", 
                             bootstrapPage(
                               div(class = "outer",
                                   tags$style(type = "text/css", ".outer {position: fixed; top: 120px; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; overflow: hidden; padding: 0}"),
                                   leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "100%"),
                                   absolutePanel(top = 80, left = 30)
                               )
                             )
                    )
        )
      )
    )
  )
```

Comment: Thanks but only issue is my navigation panel for tabs are hiding. Maps are getting placed on top

Comment: If you use 120px for top instead of 60px would that help?

Comment: Still doesn't help. I have reduced the pixels